# Question regarding the set of functions from a finite set to the set of complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Dear Math StackExchange,

Please pardon me if the nature of this question is too trivial; sometimes, the smaller thing is, the easier is it to not see it.

I am concerned about the following problems, for any finite $\Gamma$, does the set of functions $f : \Gamma \to \mathbb{C}$ form a $|\Gamma|$-dimensional vector space? In the interest of time, I decided to keep the question short. The context is learning about characters in representation theory, and got confused.

Comment: Is $\Gamma$ just an arbitrary finite set and $f\colon\Gamma\to\Bbb C$ an arbitrary map?

Comment: Yes. Given some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $g:\{1,\ldots,n\}\to\Gamma$ is a bijection, we have $f\mapsto (f\circ g(1),\ldots, f\circ g(n))$ a bijection between the set of functions and $\mathbb C^n$. This bijection induces a $\mathbb C$-vector space structure on the set of functions (or a $\mathbb Q,\mathbb R$-vector space structure if that's what you want). $\mathbb C^n$ as a $\mathbb C$ vector space has dimension $n=|\Gamma|$.

Comment: @ElliotG no, I did not mean that. I mean the set of functions forming a vector space.

Comment: The set, by itself, no; you need to define an addition and a scalar multiplication. If you define addition of functions pointswise and scalar multiplication also pointwise, then yes. For any set $X$ and any field $F$, the set $F^X$ of all functions from $X$ to $F$ forms a vector space over $F$ with pointwise addition and pointwise scalar multiplication.

Comment: @DonThousand I cannot see the last part, where you claim that $\mathbf{C}^{n}$ as a $\mathbf{C}$ vector space has dimension $n$. As far as I know, the dimension of a vector space is the cardinality of the basis. Can we discuss the basis?

Comment: See here for confirmation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Function_spaces . And yes, the dimension is the cardinality of $\Gamma$ when $\Gamma$ is finite: a basis is $f_\gamma(x) = 1$ if $x=\gamma$, $f_\gamma(x)=0$ otherwise.

Comment: @DanishA.Alvi Just take the preimage of any basis in $\mathbb C^n$ via the map I've provided to get a basis in the function space.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin yes, indeed! But still, am yet to see how the dimension of this vector space is $|\Gamma|$.

Comment: For finite $\Gamma$, the indicator functions form a basis (functions that take value $1$ at a single element of $\Gamma$ and zero elsewhere).

Comment: Ah yes, indeed, thank you! Bless all of you for your help.